# Magento 2: Add/Remove class from div if minicart hasitem

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento2.3.6

i want to add custom class if the minicart is empty and remove the class if minicart has items.

Comment: You want to add class to separate div depending on minicart has items or not?

Comment: yes. but not in seperate div. i want to add class in main div of minicart.

Answer (score 1):

I modified **minicart.phtml** as below:
i added "emptyBag" class and bind it in parent div like "scope: 'minicart_content".

```
<div class="block block-minicart"
     data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'"
     data-role="dropdownDialog"
     data-mage-init='{
        "dropdownDialog":{
        "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
        "triggerTarget":".showcart",
        "timeout": "2000",
        "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
        "closeOnEscape": true,
        "triggerClass":"active",
        "parentClass":"active",
        "buttons":[]}
     }'>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" 
         class="minicart-wrapper-section" 
         data-bind="css: { emptyBag: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == 
         false }, scope: 'minicart_content'">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below logic in minicart wrapper area

```
<span data-bind="css: { empty-cart: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }"></span>
```

Comment: already tried. but not working.

Comment: may have added outside scope it must work

Comment: @KetanBorada empty class is already there in default code in way you have suggested.

Comment: can you share the the exact place where i should add this line?

Comment: @KetanBorada i got the solution thank you for your help :)

Comment: @quickshiftin could you please share with us the solution which worked for you.

Comment: @Sathya i posted the answer, please check.